# Modifying a MySQL Query to Stop Writing Temporary Table to Disk

Tags: mysql, sql

We are improving some of our SQL queries around the site and have noticed a bottleneck with a particular SQL query that seems to dump the results into a temporary disk table.  This is expensive and of course awfully slow.

We have considered moving the MySQL temporary directory over to a RAMDISK but thought we could try to optimize it first.

**Here is the command that dumps to disk:**

```
select
  d.url,
  d.lid,
  d.title, 
  d.description, 
  d.date, 
  d.hits, 
  d.downloadratingsummary, 
  d.totalvotes, 
  d.totalcomments, 
  d.filesize, 
  d.version, 
  d.homepage, 
  d.ns_compat, 
  d.ns_des_img, 
  t.type
from downloads_downloads d
LEFT JOIN downloads_type t on d.lid = t.lid
where cid=91
ORDER BY FIELD(COALESCE(t.type,-1),1,-1,2,4,5,0,3), date DESC limit 0,20
```

Is there any simple way to reorganize/modify the above query to minimize temporary table creations on disk?

While we have experience with MySQL, performance optimization is still something new to us so any help anyone can give is always greatly appreciated.

Thanks for any help in advance.

## Structure of both referenced tables

**downloads_downloads**

[image: downloads_downloads table structure]

Indexes

[image: indexes]

**downloads_type**

[image: downloads_type table structure]

Indexes

[image: indexes2]

## Output of EXPLAIN

[image: EXPLAIN output]

### Environment:

OS X running MySQL 5.5.23 with 16GB RAM.

Comment: Please show the definition of the tables involved (including indexes) and the current execution plan

Comment: anything about your environment you want to share? hw? os? mysql version? etc

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys.  I have added table structure and index above in image format.  It seemed the easiest way to show you the structure.

Environment: OS X running MySQL 5.5.23 with 16GB RAM.

Comment: Can you give us an idea what "*awfully slow*" means in this case?  How large are tables?

Comment: Please post the result of `explain select...`

Comment: Thanks for the additional replies.  "Awfully slow" means when the server is under load.  If I run apachebench to generate queries quickly, we notice disk writes increase significantly on pages using this SQL.  This slows the server and page generation times increase on pages using the same SQL.  The downloads_downloads table has 20,475 records with a total data size of 130 MB. Output of EXPLAIN SELECT has been posted above.

Comment: Does anybody have any help or advice on this topic?

Answer (score 2):

I think these links can help to optimise this query:
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-temporary-tables.html

**First conclusion** - A filesort (a temporary table) cannot be avoided, since the query in the `ORDER BY` clause contains columns from two tables, and contains also an expression, therefore mySql cannot optimize it using indices:

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY ................ 
> These cases include the following: 
>   - You use ORDER BY with an expression that includes terms other than the key column name
>   - You are joining many tables, and the columns in the ORDER BY are not all from the first nonconstant table that is used to retrieve rows.

**Second conclusion** - because the table contains a TEXT column, MySql cannot use a *modified* (optimized) filesort algorithm, but has to use an *oryginal* algorithm. A drawback of the oryginal algorithm is that it reads table rows twice, and reads them in a random manner, which is much slower than a sequential read:

> One problem with this approach is that it reads rows twice: One time when evaluating the WHERE clause, and again after sorting the pair values. And even if the rows were accessed successively the first time (for example, if a table scan is done), the second time they are accessed randomly. (The sort keys are ordered, but the row positions are not.)

**Third conclusion** - since the table contains a TEXT column, MySql cannot use an in-memory temporary table, but has to store it on the disk:

> Some conditions prevent the use of an in-memory temporary table, in which case the server uses an on-disk table instead:
>   - Presence of a BLOB or TEXT column in the table

Taking the above into consideration, move the TEXT column into another table:

```
create table downloads_description(
  lid int(11) not null unique,
  description text,
  constraint dd_fk foreign key  (lid)
  references downloads_downloads( lid )
);

insert into downloads_description( lid, description )
select lid, description
from downloads_downloads;

alter table downloads_downloads
drop column description;
```

and then rewrite the query into:

```
SELECT 
  d.url,
  d.lid,
  d.title, 
  dd.description, 
  d.date, 
  d.hits, 
  d.downloadratingsummary, 
  d.totalvotes, 
  d.totalcomments, 
  d.filesize, 
  d.version, 
  d.homepage, 
  d.ns_compat, 
  d.ns_des_img, 
  t.type
FROM downloads_downloads d 
JOIN(
    select   d.lid, t.type
    FROM downloads_downloads d
    LEFT JOIN downloads_type t
    ON d.lid = t.lid
        WHERE cid = 81
    ORDER BY FIELD(COALESCE(t.type,-1),1,-1,2,4,5,0,3), 
          d.date DESC 
    limit 0,20
) t ON d.lid = t.lid
JOIN downloads_description dd
ON dd.lid = d.lid
ORDER BY FIELD(COALESCE(t.type,-1),1,-1,2,4,5,0,3), 
         d.date DESC 
;
```